# Would somoene have a pretty complete list of masculine nouns that have an irregular plural in -а (or in -я for nouns ending in -ь)?

Tags: существительные, множественное-число

| Singular | Plural | English |
| --- | --- | --- |
| адрес | адреса | address |
| берег | берега | shore |
| бок | бока | side |
| буфер | буфера | buffer |
| век | векa | century |
| вексель | векселя | promissory note |
| вечер | вечера | evening |
| глаз | глаза | eye |
| год | года | year |
| голос | голоса | voice |
| город | города | city |
| директор | директора | director |
| доктор | доктора | doctor |
| дом | дома | house |
| жемчуг | жемчуга | pearl |
| инспектор | инспекторa | inspector |
| катер | катера | barge |
| китель | кителя | tunic |
| колокол | колокола | bell |
| корпус | корпусa | body frame |
| край | края | edge |
| кузов | кузова | open trunk |
| купол | куполa | cupola |
| лагерь | лагеря | camp |
| лес | леса | forest |
| луг | луга | hayfield |
| мастер | мастера | foreman |
| мех | меха | fur |
| номер | номера | number |
| округ | округа | district |
| остров | острова | island |
| отпуск | отпуска | vacation |
| паспорт | паспорта | passport |
| повар | повара | cook |
| погреб | погреба | cellar |
| поезд | поезда | train |
| пояс | пояса | belt |
| профессор | профессора | professor |
| рог | рога | horn |
| рукав | рукава | sleeve |
| свитер | свитера | sweater |
| снег | снегa | snow |
| сорт | сорта | sort |
| стог | стога | haystack |
| сторож | сторожа | gateman |
| терем | терема | tower |
| том | томa | tome |
| тон | тона | tint |
| тормоз | тормоза | brake |
| учитель | учителя | teacher |
| хлеб | хлебa | cereal |
| цвет | цвета | color |
| шёлк | шелка | silk |
| штемпель | штемпеля | stamp |
| якорь | якоря | anchor |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this selection](https://gramdict.ru/search/*?symbol=%D0%BC,%D0%BC%D0%BE&circle=%E2%91%A0) from Zalizniak's *Grammatical Dictionary of Russian*.

Answer (score 2):

The following categories on Wiktionary might be of help:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Russian_nouns_ending_in_a_consonant_with_plural_-%D0%B0

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Russian_nouns_ending_in_-%D1%8C_with_plural_-%D1%8F

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Russian_nouns_ending_in_-%D0%B9_with_plural_-%D1%8F (even though that's just one word, край)

Answer (score 2):

You already have the answers to your question, but I'd like to expound on them a bit.

Please note that there are a couple of concerns:

1. Even in the list you provided in your question, there are nouns that either allow two plurals, or are declined with unstressed -ы in the nominative plural, strictly speaking. (For instance, инспектора vs. инспекторы; свитера vs. свитеры). Год is usually годы in the plural, but note: «Мои года — моё богатство», «И в дальний путь на долгие года» (from songs).
2. Some nouns have two plurals: тон is, as you stated, usually тона (светлые тона, тёплые тона) in reference to colors, but тоны in reference to music (целые тоны; в гамме встречаются тоны и полутоны). The same goes for корпус: it's корпуса in military or building contexts, but корпусы in reference to bodies or compendia of information, see in [dictionaries on gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81). So, лидер гонки обогнал своего ближайшего соперника всего на пару кóрпусов, but Этот дом состоит из трёх корпусóв.
3. The language is evolving towards this change. This can be seen in professional slang contexts, where the number of those nouns is especially notable, like: драйвера instead of normative драйверы for drivers (in computing); this is marginal, but culinary specialists sometimes talk about супá and сокá (soups and juices — note that this is considered strictly incorrect as of April 2022!). Some professional communities go even further, pluralizing feminine nouns the same way: нефтЯ for kinds of oil/petrol, but this is even more incorrect since in normal Russian, feminine nouns don't behave like that. By citing those marginal examples, I just wanted to point out that things are evolving in this direction, and it's always worth checking the latest dictionaries for what's considered the accepted norm in the modern language and what isn't.